# Issues formatting headers and baseline body text on Twenty Twenty one Theme

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've become an administrator of a website for a local club. The website's address is https://dlhg.org.uk/. It's on a "Personal" plan; I'm not the website owner so upgrading to a more expensive plan isn't up to me.

I've just updated the website so it uses the Twenty Twenty-One theme. Mostly it's an improvement but there are some problems. For example, see
https://dlhg.org.uk/programme/

1. I'd like to reduce the size of the headings and centre-align them, I can't do either
2. I'd like to reduce the size of the body text a little by changing the baseline font size, but WordPress will only let me change the font, not the font size

Here's a short Snagit video on my issues:
https://1drv.ms/v/s!AmxJyApgEAcYhulXWv0swpg0Jq0kFQ?e=p2A8eV

Could anyone help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As theme is not having font-size changing custom option field , you can change it by adding your additional css in

appearance -> customise -> additional css"

as you want to change heading size then you can add

```
.singular .entry-title {
    font-size: 44px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

change font size as per your need

and for reducing the size of the body text use

```
body p {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, PHP Geek.
Unfortunately, as the Website's current plan is "Personal" I'm unable to add CSS code - please correct me if I'm mistaken.   
I don't own the site, but I could try to get the site owner to upgrade to a "Professional" plan, at additional cost, this would give me the CSS option.
The only other option, I can see is to change the Website's  Theme. Do you know if there are any free Themes available within WordPress that have the font-size changing custom option field?

Comment: if you become administrator then you must have all the permissions to edit.
As Wordpress is free and also this is wordpress default theme which is also free. can you tell me what plan you are using.

one more solution, you can add code in theme style file. do you have access for that file?